# How to change node runtime version

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I want to use nodejs version 0.6 or above in cloud foundry . currently my app uses v0.4.12. 
I tried below manifest.yaml but No luck.
what should i do next?
any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
--- 
applications: 
  .: 
    name: shanbhag
    framework: 
      name: node06
      info: 
        mem: 64M
        description: Node.js Application
        exec: 
    url: ${name}.${target-base}
    runtime: node06
    mem: 64M
    instances: 1
    services: 
      mongodb-fc654: 
        type: mongodb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you deploy the app, specify the runtime version like so;

```
vmc push myapp --runtime=node06
```

or for node.js 0.8

```
vmc push myapp --runtime=node08
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a package.json file? If so, update the engines section:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  }
```

Also, the Cloud Foundry documentation at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/nodejs/nodejs.html has some information on this subject. You might need to run some of the commands that they mention.

Comment: Thanks Hector. link helped me. I deleted my app and ran push command. worked successfully. I have marked another as answer as i feel that correct command which would help anyone else in future. Thanks again